# What's a good strategy? Testing with Mocks in C# without default Virtual

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking, clr, virtual-functions

I ran into a pretty big short-coming with C# in regards to mocking and testing. And my solutions to the issue are undesirable.

I have three classes that come together to perform some functionality. It doesn't make any sense to use interfaces or to explicitly declare any of the methods virtual as the design doesn't really call for extension or polymorphism. Any effort to make the classes reusable would only complicate the code.

However, because I have not explicitly declared any of methods virtual, I can't mock out the classes and record their calls through a frame work. The pseudo-code (using Rhino.Mocks) would look something like this.

```
var b = mockRepo.StrickMock<ClassB>();
var c = mockRepo.StrickMock<ClassC>();
var classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest{ B = b, C = c};

Expect.Call( b.MethodA );
Expect.Call( c.MethodB );

mockRepo.ReplayAll();
classUnderTest.DoSomething();
mockRepo.VerifyAll();
```

As it stands, I would have to make b.MethodA and c.MethodB virtual for this to work. Alternatively I could extract the interfaces of ClassB and ClassC and mock those. But as I said before, this would only serve to complicate things. I could alter the design of the classes to make it more reusable, but this would also complicate matters and functionality has a very low chance for reuse.

How should I solve this issue and still strive to maintain simplicity between the dependencies and the executing code? Have I missed an option? What approach would you prefer to take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reoccurring theme in the SOLID principles is that you should depend upon abstractions (open closed principle / dependency inversion principle). Whether you use interfaces or abstract classes with virtual methods, mocking is about testing the relationship or contract between objects.

If you use a mocking framework, these tools use Dynamic Proxy to dynamically generate an implementation for behavior-based verification. This strategy implies that you are using abstractions that can be replaced.

Other frameworks like TypeMock use the Profiler API to intercept and rewrite IL before it gets JIT compiled. It's a paid product and a bit slow, but it allows you to intercept anything.

Personally, given the options. I'd take the free tool and design towards abstractions. The code will be less flexible but overall more predictable and easier to test.

Comment: I guess the point I am trying to make, is that it's bizarre to have to explicitly set methods as virtual just to test them. It's somewhat misleading, as virtual is a cue to override a class member in a derivative. But in reality, all I would be doing is creating an extendable type so that I can test it... If by default, these members were extendable, then we wouldn't have a semantic issue.

Comment: But anyway, I think you may be right... I might have to design towards abstraction in order to test, and just decide depending on context whether interfaces or the virtual keyword is the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

The interfaces are a seam for your unit-tests to plug in fakes easily. I don't see how they would complicate things (apart from increasing the number of types).

The interfaces make the contract between the caller and the callee explicit. Also the interfaces provide opportunities for creating a 'system of names'. The interface also makes it easier to see members that don't belong (as opposed to classes which can attract unrelated methods).

In summary, a small price to pay.

Comment: I don't agree that interfaces are a small price to pay. In a single instance maybe, but extract this to a large body of code and you have a mess. They are useful to describe intent (if named properly), but only really when developing a code you expect to extend. However, the reality of re-usability in OOP is actually a big disappointment. In most circumstances, code is not reused as much as a programmer might intend. My thoughts are unless you have a good reason to create a polymorphic type, it's complicated and premature to design everything in your code base with that goal.

Comment: @Nicholas - +1 to Reuse is Overrated :) I'm not advocating putting an interface in front of each class - I'd review the design again if I find a plethora of roles/interfaces. I'd put an interface only where I need 2 implementations to be plugged in. A fake/mock/stub qualifies as an alternate implementation even "it is needed only for tests and not in production". This drives the need for an interface. On the other hand: if A depends on B and C, and both are in-memory fast testable classes. I'd test an with real deps (no need for IB and IC). If B and C are internal, no B and C tests too.

Comment: agreed. It would be fine to use the real implementations. It's just that in this instance I would have to expose state to be able to test it. That's not really a great option. I can however, inject a member into class B to be get a handle on it's state. Unfortunately, Class C uses the File system, and I don't know of a good way to mock File or Directory. Maybe I should look closer at this though.

Comment: @Nicholas - you shouldn't have to "expose state for testing". A change in state should have some observable change in the exposed behavior. Monitor that change in your tests. Also if a dependency uses "test-unfriendly" subsystems like FileSystems/Network IO/Databases etc.. they need to be put behind a role and mocked/faked so that the tests for the calling types remain fast/snappy

Answer (score 1):

It's less than ideal to test your functionality by making sure your code calls its dependencies' routines in a certain way.  Your test is now tied to the implementation of your method instead of the behavior you expect.

I would recommend starting with the question: What behaviors am I trying to test?  A behavior is a set of preconditions, an action you want to invoke (i.e. a method call), and a set of post conditions you want to test.  For example, if you wanted to test that pushing an item onto a stack increases its count by one, you would write a test called:

```
public void Push_OnAnyStack_IncreasesCountByOne()
```

More generally, you can name your tests with the following template:

```
public void MethodToCall_WithGivenStateAndInputs_PerformsExpectedResult
```

I agree with you that introducing interfaces for interfaces' sake can be overengineering.  So you should look at your code structure and see if there's a way you can test the behavior you want to test by setting up preconditions (arranging your test), acting by calling a particular method, and asserting on postconditions by querying the state of the object you're testing.  This way you're less concerned about how your method is implemented and more concerned about the behavior it performs.  If you find that this is impossible, it's an indication that you need to refactor your design to make responsibilities clear. It may also be an indication that interfaces are actually the right solution.

Comment: Appreciate your comment, but my dependencies define my behaviour. There is more than one way to test a class, & a clean comparable state is not always possible. The method of testing I am performing actually describes testable behaviour. It's akin to saying, "When I set up my System with this state, I expect my dependencies to behave in this way". This is in fact usually why you use mocks. I could hand-roll my own mocks & then maintain a reporting state within them, but that's time consuming. Anyway, it still has the virtual member problem. Incidentally, Java does not have this same issue.

Comment: @Nicholas - can you expand on your last sentence?  It seems like Java has the exact same issue - if you have a non-virtual method you can't override it in subclasses.  If you want to allow subclasses to override it, make it virtual (don't mark it final); if you don't, make it non-virtual (do mark it final).  Either way, you should be making a deliberate decision.

Comment: By default Java methods are virtual. So there is no confusion with the virtual keyword. (As in, did the developer mean for the method to be extended, or was it just a work-around for mocking.) Java does use final to prevent methods from being extended. From a user standpoint, I feel like this a preferable design, though there are clear compiler and runtime advantages to having a single V-table by default for all class methods.

Comment: @Nicholas - If the dependencies define your behaviour, then you have a few options, all of which depend on using interfaces:

* Continue doing what you're doing using a mock on the interface instead of the concrete class that you inject through the constructor
* Create a simulator class that inherits from the interface where your test can query on its state instead of querying that certain methods were called.  This may not be possible given your situation, but it's worth calling out.

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely opt for the interfaces.